# Problemas para visualizar una página web por la zona horaria

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, time, timezone

espero que estén bien.
Soy un estudiante de matemáticas y cuando tengo dudas acerca de algo pregunto en un foro llamado rincón matemático.
Nunca había tenido problemas para entrar pero desde hace un par de días me aparece esto:

**2: strftime() [function.strftime]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected 'America/Buenos_Aires' for 'ART/-3.0/no DST' instead
Archivo: /www/rinconmatematico.com/htdocs/foros/Sources/Subs.php
Línea: 879**

Busqué en internet qué debía hacer y de todo lo que entendí, debía agregar las siguientes lineas a un archivo llamado php.ini :
*date_default_timezone_set("America/Mexico_City");
date.timezone="America/Mexico_City"*

Tengo Ubuntu así que lo que hice fue simplemente ir a el directorio /etc que es donde se encontraba el archivo, lo edité con nano pero sigo teniendo el mismo problema :( 
Podrían ayudarme por favor?
De antemano gracias. Saludos.

Comment: El problema es del sitio, no de tu equipo. Deberías reportarlo.

Comment: Hola Sal gracias por tu respuesta, según yo lo reporté pero no he tenido respuesta hasta ahora de ningún administrador, supongo que es cuestión de tiempo, muchas gracias, por un momento creí que era mi equipo. Saludos.